# Error: while processing statement: FAILED: Hive Internal Error: hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories must be true

Tags: hadoop, recursion, optimization, hive, bigdata

i stumbled in an error

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Hive Internal Error:
>   hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories must be true if any one of
>   following is true: hive.optimize.listbucketing ,
>   mapred.input.dir.recursive and hive.optimize.union.remove.

this error occured when i tried to load data recursively from HDFS directory to hive table

i tried to set following parameters:

> SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=true; SET
>   hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;
>   SETmapred.input.dir.recursive=true;

but it keeps throwing the same error, what could be wrong?

thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with Hue in Cloudera. Currently, I am using CDH 5.11.2 just experienced this issue while trying to set the same statements.

If you connect through beeline (command line) to access hive and perform your set statements and queries there, it should work. I just verified this.